# Error: Invalid cache option true found. Expected "memory"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hosting

this error shows in cmd using rhc tail socialinteractive 
i hosted this site to openshfit i use swig and modules consolidate and swing for  template 
guide me to slove this error

```
Error: Invalid cache option true found. Expected "memory" or { get: function (ke
    y) { ... }, set: function (key, value) { ... } }.
        at validateOptions (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/run
    time/repo/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:113:15)
        at parse (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/runtime/repo/
    node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:339:5)
        at Object.precompile (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/r
    untime/repo/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:486:23)
        at Object.compile (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/runt
    ime/repo/node_modules/swig/lib/swig.js:606:16)
        at Function.exports.swig.render (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c
    /app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:246:56)
        at /var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
    dules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:146:25
        at read (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/runtime/repo/n
    ode_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:91:22)
        at /var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/runtime/repo/node_mo
    dules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:144:9
        at readPartials (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/runtim
    e/repo/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:114:33)
        at View.engine (/var/lib/openshift/5453580c500446bfbc000d3c/app-root/runtime
    /repo/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:139:5)
    GET / 500 4.312 ms - -
```

Answer (score 2):

This is consolidate.js bug, not OpenShift bug.

It has been already addressed upstream, see:
https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/pull/134

1. Either you need to update your consolidate.js npm package once they release version greater than 0.10.0.
2. Or you can use the following workaround (as [suggested by @truongminh](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/commit/e84860d55b2cb938c9a5525f83feba7f86dfeba7#commitcomment-6427166)):

   > app.locals.cache = "memory"

Comment: If anyone else is using co-views I had to update it to >2.0.0 to get it to work.... and iojs (that I also used) to above 2.
Hope this help